# REDIS connection environment variable

Tags: redis

I have an application server that is connecting to an external redis server for pub/sub, I am currently using a redis python library, when I connect using the library it assumes the redis server is started locally at `127.0.0.1:6379`. Is there an environment variable that sets the default redis connection to `127.0.0.1:6379`? I can specify the server end point in my application code but I would prefer to use an environment variable if one is available.

Comment: What is the library you are using ?

Comment: `brukva` library for tornado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an environmental setting, but a default setting. Check the [source code](https://github.com/evilkost/brukva/blob/master/brukva/client.py):

```
def __init__(self, host='localhost', port=6379, password=None,
...
)
```

Change it in the [configuration file](https://github.com/evilkost/brukva/blob/master/redis.conf):

```
# Accept connections on the specified port, default is 6379.
# If port 0 is specified Redis will not listen on a TCP socket.
#port 6379

# If you want you can bind a single interface, if the bind option is not
# specified all the interfaces will listen for incoming connections.
#
# bind 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Redis is on a separate server, what configuration file are you referring to?

Comment: @S-K' the one I linked

Comment: @dawud : How to make IPv6 connections to listen only to local connections?